# How can I convert the output of IntegerString[n, "Base64"] back into base 10?

Tags: character-encoding, number-bases

`BaseForm[]` does not allow conversion to bases above base 36. However, `IntegerString[]` can convert a number `n` into a base 64 string.

```
n = 1000000000000;
s = IntegerString[n, "Base64"]
(* "OjUpRAA" *)
```

What is the cleanest way to convert `"OjUpRAA"` back into the number `1000000000000`?

None of the expressions below do the job:

```
ImportString[s, "Base64"]
ImportString[s, {"Base64", "String"}]
FromDigits[s, 64]
FromDigits[s, "Base64"]
FromDigits[Characters[s], 64]
BaseDecode[s, "Base64"]
```

Comment: Base64 does not mean using a set of 64 digits. Base64 is a binary encoding scheme. It's a way to turn a stream of bits (which could represent any type of data, e.g. string or numeric or anything else) into a stream of textual characters. Obviously such a scheme will use 64 characters, and you could interpret these as digits, but I don't think Mathematica will assume that a Base64 encoded snippet of text will represent a base-64 representation of a number.

Comment: You could supply the reverse mapping yourself. You'd split the string up into characters, replace each character with it's digit (each digit represented in base-10) and then use FromDigits on that sequence.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: any Mathematica object can be converted to/from Base64 with the encoder `enc = BaseEncode@*BinarySerialize` and the decoder `dec = BinaryDeserialize@*BaseDecode`. This encoding preserves the internal structure of the object (not just its value). For example, `enc[1000000000000]` gives `"ODpMABCl1OgAAAA="` instead of the OP's `"OjUpRAA"`. Anything can be encoded: `enc[Exp[x]]` gives `"ODpmAnMFUG93ZXJzAUVzCEdsb2JhbGB4"`, and `enc@MandelbrotSetPlot[]` gives something huge (but decodable).

Answer (score 5):

Here's something you could try. First, build the mapping to "decode" a Base64 encoding as if it represented a digit sequence:

```
Base64ToDigitMap = Table[IntegerString[i, "Base64"] -> i, {i, 0, 63}]
```

Now, split up your Base64-encoded string into characters, apply this map to it, and use FromDigits:

```
FromDigits[Characters["OjUpRAA"] /. Base64ToDigitMap, 64]
```

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of IntegerString is FromDigits. However FromDigits does not support "Base64". Therefore, do not use IntegerString, use ExportString instead, which has an inverse ImportString that works with Base64.

```
n = 1000000000000;
ex = ExportString[ToString@n, "Base64"]
(* MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMA== *)
```

To decode this:

```
ImportString[s, "Base64"]
(* "1000000000000" *)
```

Comment: -1: This does not answer the question as written ("What is the cleanest way to convert `"OjUpRAA"` back into the number `1000000000000?`")